# Close Dialog Warning has Changed

Tags: bug, status-completed, close-dialog

When I try to close a just closed question, The dialog used to say

> The question is already closed, Please refresh the page

But now, The dialog is mixed with the other dialog and says

> You may load the close dialog every 3 seconds

[image: But Why??]

And yes, I *did* wait for 3, 4 and even 5 minutes,

I also waited [6 to 8 minutes as mentioned by Tunaki](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/325919/close-dialog-warning-has-changed#comment355817_325919), But same issue. I think I need to wait for [6 to 8 weeks](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19514/311398).

---

Steps to repro -

1. See a bad/offtopic question (Please don't ask a bad question).
2. Wait till the question is closed (May take a long time)
3. Click on *close* link, once you know it is closed.

Comment: You should have waited [6 to 8 minutes](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19514).